# Jquery Tip tool needed

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am using Jquery. I like some recommendations from the users on which plugin would be the best for what I need. I have hyperlinks on my page. What I like to do is on hover over a hyperlink, I like a tooltip to come up. It should do a JSON and fetch data from the server to show.

I looked at QTip (jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js) but wasn't able to get it to work as from reading online it may be buggy.

Just wondering if there are others plugins out that are popularly used that I can make use of.

Comment: Have you tried Google?  And why not create a jsfiddle with your QTip code that does not work, so we can take a look at it?

Comment: Look at qTip again.  This time, [look at the top of the page where it tells you it's been superseded for version 2.0](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery ui 1.9 tooltip may reach your requirement

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content

You can set custom content which is from server.